# How to run a lookup query inside Doctrine2 Entity with Symfony3

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a basic Doctrine2 entity, but one of the fields needs some formatting applied to it to turn it from a database primary key, into a user-visible "friendly ID".

I want to put the formatting logic in only one place, so that if it ever changes, it only has to be updated once.

Part of the formatting involves looking up a string from the database and using that as a prefix, as this value will be different for different installations.  I am a bit stuck, because within the entity I can't (and probably shouldn't) look up the database to retrieve this prefix.

However I am not sure how else to go about this.

Here is some pseudocode illustrating what I am trying to do:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

// This is also an entity, annotations/getters/setters omitted for brevity.
class Lookup {
    protected $key;
    protected $value;
}

class Person {
    /**
     * Database primary key
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * Get the person's display ID.
     *
     * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
     * @Serializer\SerializedName("friendlyId")
     */
    protected function getFriendlyId()
    {
        if ($this->person === null) return null;

        //$prefix = 'ABC';
        // The prefix should be loaded from the DB, somehow
        $lookup = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Lookup')->find('USER_PREFIX');
        $prefix = $lookup->getValue();

        return $prefix . $this->person->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess one way would be to use the Lifecycle Callbacks (events). For instance that would be either `postLoad()` or `postLoadHandler()` depending on the implementation. Take a look at these and I can help out a bit more if necessary.

Comment: How about adding a `prefix`  property to the Person class and fill it with the constructor when instanciated?

Comment: As you pointed out yourself, doing queries from inside an entity is something to be avoided.  Consider making sort of a PersonView class to act as a facade to the Person but returns view formatted information.

Comment: @Veve: Doctrine instantiates the class for me, so it would have to be something that is done in the constructor itself as most of the time the objects are supplied to my code and I'm not the one instantiating the classes.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [event listeners](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html#configuring-the-listener-subscriber) using symfony and doctrine and listen to `postLoad` event by registering the service

```
services:
    person.postload.listener:
        class: AppBundle\EventListener\PersonPostLoadListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Now in your listener you will have an access to entity manager

```
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;
use AppBundle\Entity\Person;

class PersonPostLoadListener
{
    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $args->getEntity();

        if (!$entity instanceof Person) {
            return;
        }

        $entityManager = $args->getEntityManager();
        $lookup  =$entityManager->getRepository('AppBundle\Entity\Lookup')->findOneBy(array(
            'key'=> 'USER_PREFIX'
        ));
        $entity->setFriendlyId($entity->getId().$lookup->getValue());
        //echo "<pre>";dump($entity);echo "</pre>";die('Call')
    }
}
```

And in your person entity you need to define an un mapped property for your id and its getter and setter method like

```
class Person
{
    private $friendlyId;

    public function getFriendlyId()
    {
        return $this->friendlyId;
    }

    public function setFriendlyId($friendlyId)
    {
        return $this->friendlyId = $friendlyId;
    }

}
```